# Not able to authenticate laravel-4 login

Tags: php, laravel-4, database-schema

My user table structure is as under, I am not able to authenticate my login form. Please let me know what should be changed in overall laravel config files? I am getting "boolean false" as result when using dd(Auth::attempt($user));

```
Schema::create('users', function($table){
$table->increments('userId');
$table->string('userName');
$table->string('userPassword');
$table->timestamps();
});

// My UserController function is as under
    public function postLogin() {
        $user = array(
            'userName' => Input::get('username'),
            'userPassword' => Input::get('password')
        );

        //dd(Auth::attempt($user));

        if( Auth::attempt($user) ) {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'You are logged in');
        } else {
            return Redirect::route('login')
                ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
```

// Here is my model

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public static $rules = array(
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    );

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('userPassword');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Second, I am getting "created_at, updated_at" by migrations when using "$table->timestamps()", please suggest me how can I name "created_at, updated_at" like camel case "createdAt, updatedAt" as my other fields.

Note: *Register is working fine for me.*

Comment: Can you post the controller code for your login?

Comment: If you can add your User eloquent Model also that might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: woops just realized that you must've already solved this

```
$table->increments('userId');
```

You're using userId for your primary key instead of ID, but your Eloquent model is not aware of this. You need to add the following line to your User model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'userId';  //this variable is defaulted to 'id'
```

The following should also be changed:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->password;  
}
```

You're not using "password" as your password column. Change it to:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->userPassword;  
}
```

The autogenerated code in the User model assumes that you use the default field names [defined by Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#creating-a-migration), so you need to make sure that the User model and auth config match the changes you made to the table.

Comment: Yes I had solved this problem, anyways your answer confirm my doubt. Thanks